Ramsey number lower bound $R(3,2n)>2R(3,n)-2$

Is it true that $R(3,2n)>2R(3,n)-2$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$?

I tried to construct a similar argument to this one.
Denote $a=R(3,n)$. Take two edge-coloring of $K_{a-1}$ without a red chromatic $K_3$ and without a blue chromatic $K_n$. Define $G:=K_{2a-2}=K_{a-1}\cup K_{a-1}$, coloring in blue the edges between the two copies of $K_{a-1}$. Every $3$ vertices in $G$ either reside all in the same copy of $K_{a-1}$ (which is red-$K_3$-free), or is split among the two copies; in both cases, the resulting $K_3$ is not a red monochromatic triangle. Similarly, every $2n$ vertices in $G$ has at least $n$ of them in one copy of $K_{a-1}$, which is blue-$K_n$-free.
Is there a simpler approach, or an elementary approach yielding a better lower bound?

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Your proof is fine, and is the natural and obvious way to do it. But doesn't it actually show that $R(3,2n-1)\gt2R(3,n)-2$?
